# Elasticsearch field collapsing with minimum inner hits count

Tags: elasticsearch

When using field collapsing, is there a way to filter out results which inner hits count is less than a give threshold?

In an hotel database I want to find hotels with three cheapest available rooms cheaper than X. Each document has a `hotel_id`, `room_id` and `price`. If the hotel has not 3 available rooms cheaper than X, I cannot do anything with it.

So I do a search for rooms cheaper than X, sorted by price, collapsing with `hotel_id`, but I want to see only groups that contains 3 rooms in inner hits, otherwise that hotel result is unusable. With the `size` parameter I define a maximum, but I cannot find a way to define a minimum.

Aggregation is not an option due performance constraints.